# how to speed up PyMC markov model?

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

Is there a way to speed up this simple PyMC model? On 20-40 data points, it takes ~5-11 seconds to fit.

```
import pymc
import time
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

# prior probability of rain
p_rain = 0.5
variables = OrderedDict()
# rain observations
data = [True, True, True, True, True,
        False, False, False, False, False]*4
num_steps = len(data)
p_rain_given_rain = 0.9
p_rain_given_norain = 0.2
p_umbrella_given_rain = 0.8
p_umbrella_given_norain = 0.3
for n in range(num_steps):
    if n == 0:
        # Rain node at time t = 0
        rain = pymc.Bernoulli("rain_%d" %(n), p_rain)
    else:
        rain_trans = \
          pymc.Lambda("rain_trans",
                      lambda prev_rain=variables["rain_%d" %(n-1)]: \
                      prev_rain*p_rain_given_rain + (1-prev_rain)*p_rain_given_norain)
        rain = pymc.Bernoulli("rain_%d" %(n), p=rain_trans)
    umbrella_obs = \
      pymc.Lambda("umbrella_obs",
                  lambda rain=rain: \
                  rain*p_umbrella_given_rain + (1-rain)*p_umbrella_given_norain)
    umbrella = pymc.Bernoulli("umbrella_%d" %(n), p=umbrella_obs,
                              observed=True,
                              value=data[n])
    variables["rain_%d" %(n)] = rain
    variables["umbrella_%d" %(n)] = umbrella

print "running on %d points" %(len(data))
all_vars = variables.values()
t_start = time.time()
model = pymc.Model(all_vars)
m = pymc.MCMC(model)
m.sample(iter=2000)
t_end = time.time()
print "\n%.2f secs to run" %(t_end - t_start)
```

With only 40 data points, it takes 11 seconds to run:

```
running on 40 points
 [-----------------100%-----------------] 2000 of 2000 complete in 11.5 sec
11.54 secs to run
```

(with 80 points it takes 20 seconds). This is a toy example. The expressions inside `Lambda()` that determine transitions are in practice more complex. This basic code structure is flexible (whereas encoding the model with transition matrices is less flexible). Is there a way to keep a similar code structure but get better performance? Happy to switch to PyMC3 if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of pymc are you using? In pymc documentation for 2.3.6 I can't find the Bernoulli function, only Bernoulli_like [Doc](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/).

Comment: I have a similar concern about optimization (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205123/how-to-fit-a-method-belonging-to-an-instance-with-pymc3)

Answer (score 6):

Markov-Chain Monte Carlo is a known sequential problem.

This means its runtime proportional to number of steps and run time of your fitness function.

There are some tricks you can do, however:

- Use PyPy (requires rewrite, pymc not supported)
- Use Gibbs sampling to improve your next step
- Use multiple start points (in parallel)
- Use multiple branches (in parallel)
- Use heuristic to stop the chain earlier
- Use approximation for points that are close to already computed

Harder approaches:

- Use Numba (compiles fitness function to machine code)
- rewrite your fitness function in C (or similar)
- use native MCMC code (non-Python, requires the above)

Finally there's a lot of research out there:

http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ndjw1/docs/pbc.pdf

https://sites.google.com/site/parallelmcmc/

http://pyinsci.blogspot.com/2010/12/efficcient-mcmc-in-python.html (pypy)

Comment: Being an answer to a very general question, I tried to stay concise. Please comment for specifics...

Comment: In pymc3, the default sampling is NUTS; is Gibbs faster?

Comment: I'm not an expert, rather see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311813/can-somebody-explain-to-me-nuts-in-english . My 2c: it may depend on the problem; https://gsejournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12711-019-0515-1 says overall performance was "comparable"