# pymc3 likelihood math with non-theano function

Tags: python, theano, bayesian, pymc3

I'm new to doing Bayesian inference.  I'm trying to adapt a grid search code I wrote to Bayesian Monte Carlo Markov Chain approach, and I'm using PyMC3.  My problem is that the code has to call a function that can't be rewritten in theano syntax.  (The function relies on a piece of Fortran code in an f2py wrapper.)

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Independent parameters
    x = pm.Normal('x', sx, sd=incx*float(nrangex)/2.0)
    y = pm.Normal('y', sy, sd=incy*float(nrangey)/2.0)
    depth = pm.Normal('depth', sdepth, sd=incdepth*float(nrangedepth)/2.0)
    length = pm.Normal('length', slength, sd=inclength*float(nrangelength)/2.0)
    width = pm.Normal('width', swidth, sd=incwidth*float(nrangewidth)/2.0)
    strike = pm.Normal('strike', sstrike, sd=incstrike*float(nrangestrike)/2.0)
    dip = pm.Normal('dip', sdip, sd=incdip*float(nrangedip)/2.0)
    rake = pm.Normal('rake', srake, sd=incrake*float(nrangerake)/2.0)

    # Model (This is the part that doesn't work.)
    los_disp =  zne2los(getdisp(lon2km(dsidata['lon'], x), lat2km(dsidata['lat'], y), depth, length, width, strike, dip, rake))

    # Likelihood
    odisp = pymc3.Normal('los_disp', mu = los_disp, sd = 0.5, observed = dsidata['disp'])

    # Sampling
    trace = pm.sample(100)
```

What this code is trying to do is invert for earthquake source parameters from ground displacement data.  The dsidata data frame contains ground displacement data as a function of latitude and longitude.  I'm trying to solve for the eight earthquake source parameters that produce the best fit to this ground surface displacement.

The getdisp function simply cannot be rewritten for theano because it calls a piece of Fortran that forward models ground surface displacement from earthquake source parameters.  Is there a way to compile non-theano code into a theano form?  Is there another way do this?

Since I'm new to this, and I can't find many great examples to look at, there may well be other errors in the code.  Are there other mistakes I'm making?

Comment: Yes, the pymc3 doc is quite bad and you do not find examples on the web as soon as you are not in an easy case where many examples are unnecessary... It is an issue the pymc3 module looks so great but I 'm sure I use only 10% of his capacity just because there is no solid documentation... I experienced several such hard questionings with pymc3 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205123/how-to-fit-a-method-belonging-to-an-instance-with-pymc3 for instance) and each time I loose at least several weeks... In the meantime is there any hope you make it without pymc3 ?  pymc2 for instance ?